# Не могу достучаться с хоста до gRPC-сервера запущенного в Docker

Tags: golang, docker, grpc

Есть gRPC-сервер на Go, запущенный в Docker на порту 7777 (порт проброшен на хост). Также есть клиент на хосте, который подключается к серверу, но как только он отправляет сообщение то падает с ошибкой:

`"rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = \"error reading server preface: read tcp 127.0.0.1:36206->127.0.0.1:7777: read: connection reset by peer\""`

Dockerfile сервера:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

COPY --from=base /build/server/server /app/server

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 7777

CMD [ "./server" ]
```

(В base образе всё компилируется и я достаю оттуда только бинарь сервера)

И запускаю это дело следующим образом:

```
$ docker build -t server --file=./server/build/Dockerfile ./
$ docker run --rm -it --name server_app -p 7777:7777 server
```

Клиента запускаю на хосте через `go run`

Причём при запуске обоих на хосте всё прекрасно работает

Comment: Приложите, пожалуйста, больше информации о конфигурации сервера, клиента и какие порты вы пробрасываете в контейнере

Comment: Очень тяжело рассуждать про ошибку без файла конфигурации сервера (или же настроек сервера в коде), потому что именно с его стороны происходит "что-то" с соединением, вследствие чего вы падаете с такой ошибкой. Прикрепляю ресурсы, где может быть решение вашей проблемы:
https://dev.to/thanhphuchuynh/understanding-connection-reset-by-peer-in-golang-a-troubleshooting-guide-41pf

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75143542/connection-reset-by-peer-in-python-grpc

https://serverfault.com/questions/768087/pushing-to-local-docker-registry-gives-connection-reset-error